# Could not find lint-checks-27.0.1.jar

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I created an app using android studio and flutter plugin, and I used url_launcher lib, and every things worked fine until I update my gradle and some plugins :(

Now when I hit run or build gives me this error :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Parameter format not correct -
Note: D:\Flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.7.2\android\src\main\java\io        \flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find lint-checks-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.0.1/lint-checks-    27.0.1.jar
   > Could not find intellij-core-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-        core:27.0.1).
 Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-    core/27.0.1/intellij-core-27.0.1.jar
   > Could not find kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-    compiler:27.0.1).
 Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.0.1/kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more     log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I updated the "url_launcher-5.7.2" to the last version,
I tried to use VPN , but nothing works,

if I click on the links that show in the debug , I can download the files, But I don't know where I have to put them ...

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.0.1/lint-checks-27.0.1.jar

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/27.0.1/intellij-core-27.0.1.jar

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/27.0.1/kotlin-compiler-27.0.1.jar

**Note:**
If remove url_launcher-5.7.2 , The project will work again.